# Detect if JSON file has field

Tags: go

My app reads settings from a config file:

```
file, _ := os.Open("config.json")
config := config.Config{}
err := json.NewDecoder(file).Decode(&config)
if err != nil {
    //handle err
}
```

My JSON config file looks something like this:

```
{
    "site" : {
        "url" : "https://example.com"
    },
    "email" : {
        "key" : "abcde"
    }
}
```

My structs are:

```
type Site struct {
    Url  string
}

type Email struct {
    Key  string
}

type Config struct {
    Site   Site
    Email  Email
}
```

I would like the option of removing the `email` field from the JSON file to indicate that no email account will be used so:

```
{
    "site" : {
        "url" : "https://example.com"
    }
}
```

How do I detect if a specific field exists in the JSON file in Go so something on the lines of:

```
if (Email field found in JSON file) {
    output "You want to receive emails"
} else {
    output "No emails for you!"
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change `Config` to

```
type Config struct {
  Site   Site
  Email  *Email
}
```

Use `c.Email != nil` to test if email is specified as a string value in the JSON file.  If `c.Email == nil`, then email is not specified or `null`.

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/xi43WEe4dp)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've asked a similar question recently and should have realised it applies to this too.

Comment: It's worth noting that `c.Email` will also be `nil` if the JSON file has `"email": null`. http://play.golang.org/p/zOG3qAd0jP

Comment: @Ainar-G, maybe you could find another answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601367/golang-json-field-set-to-null-vs-field-not-there