# JSON field set to null vs field not there

Tags: json, go, struct, null

Is there a way, in golang, to see if I can differentiate between a json field being set to null vs a json field not being there when unmarshalled into a struct? Because both set the value in the struct to be nil, but I need to know if the field was there to begin with and to see if someone set it to null.

```
{
  "somefield1":"somevalue1",
  "somefield2":null
}
```

VS

```
{
  "somefield1":"somevalue1",
}
```

Both jsons will be nil when unmarshalled into a struct.
Any useful resources will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `json.RawMessage` to "delay" the unmarshaling process to determine the raw byte before deciding to do something:

```
var data = []byte(`{
        "somefield1":"somevalue1",
        "somefield2": null
}`)

type Data struct {
    SomeField1 string          
    SomeField2 json.RawMessage
}

func main() {
    d := &Data{}

    _ = json.Unmarshal(data, &d)

    fmt.Println(d.SomeField1)

    if len(d.SomeField2) > 0 {
        if string(d.SomeField2) == "null" {
            fmt.Println("somefield2 is there but null")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("somefield2 is there and not null")
            // Do something with the data
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("somefield2 doesn't exist")
    }
}
```

See the playground https://play.golang.org/p/Wganpf4sbO

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie to Go, and I am not sure but wouldn't this say it is null if say SomeField2 was "hello"?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok thanks for the elaboration edited as commented.

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes I've added the conditions to the code to cover that.

Answer (score 16):

If you're on Go 1.18+ you can use a simple generic struct to know when a JSON value is `undefined` or `null`:

```golang
type Optional[T any] struct {
    Defined bool
    Value   *T
}

// UnmarshalJSON is implemented by deferring to the wrapped type (T).
// It will be called only if the value is defined in the JSON payload.
func (o *Optional[T]) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    o.Defined = true
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &o.Value)
}
```

That's all, you can then just use this type in your structs:

```golang
type Payload struct {
    Field1 Optional[string] `json:"field1"`
    Field2 Optional[bool]   `json:"field2"`
    Field3 Optional[int32]  `json:"field3"`
}
```

And you'll be able to use the `Defined` field to know if the field was `null` or `undefined`.

Check this playground link for a full example: https://go.dev/play/p/JZfZyVVUABz

### Original answer (pre-generics)

Another way to do this, with a custom type:

```golang
// OptionalString is a struct that represents a JSON string that can be
// undefined (Defined == false), null (Value == nil && Defined == true) or 
// defined with a string value
type OptionalString struct {
    Defined bool
    Value   *string
}

// UnmarshalJSON implements the json.Unmarshaler interface.
// When called, it means that the value is defined in the JSON payload.
func (os *OptionalString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // UnmarshalJSON is called only if the key is present
    os.Defined = true
    return json.Unmarshal(data, &os.Value)
}


// Payload represents the JSON payload that you want to represent.
type Payload struct {
    SomeField1 string         `json:"somefield1"`
    SomeField2 OptionalString `json:"somefield2"`
}
```

You can then just use the regular `json.Unmarshal` function to get your values, for example:

```golang
    var p Payload
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{
            "somefield1":"somevalue1",
            "somefield2":null
        }`), &p)
    fmt.Printf("Should be defined == true and value == nil: \n%+v\n\n", p)


    p = Payload{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"somefield1":"somevalue1"}`), &p)
    fmt.Printf("Should be defined == false \n%+v\n\n", p)
    
    p = Payload{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{
            "somefield1":"somevalue1",
            "somefield2":"somevalue2"
        }`), &p)
    fmt.Printf("Parsed should be defined == true and value != nil \n%+v\n", p)
    if p.SomeField2.Value != nil {
      fmt.Printf("SomeField2's value is %s", *p.SomeField2.Value)
    }
```

Should give you this output:

```
Should be defined == true and value == nil: 
{SomeField1:somevalue1 SomeField2:{Defined:true Value:<nil>}}

Should be defined == false 
{SomeField1:somevalue1 SomeField2:{Defined:false Value:<nil>}}

Parsed should be defined == true and value != nil 
{SomeField1:somevalue1 SomeField2:{Defined:true Value:0xc000010370}}
SomeField2's value is somevalue2
```

Link to the playground with the full example: https://play.golang.org/p/AUDwPKHBs62

Do note that you **will need one struct for each type you want to wrap**, so, if you need an optional number you'll need to create an `OptionalFloat64` (all JSON numbers can be 64 bit floats) struct with a similar implementation.
If/when generics land in Go, this could be simplified to a single generic struct.

Answer (score 7):

Good question.

I believe you can use https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage as:

```
type MyMessage struct {
  somefield1 string
  somefield2 json.RawMessage
}
```

So after unmarshalling you should have `[]byte("null")` in case of `null` and `nil` if missing.

Here is a playground code: https://play.golang.org/p/UW8L68K068

Answer (score 5):

If you unmarshall the object into a map[string]interface{} then you can just check if a field is there

```
type unMarshalledObject map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(input, unMarshalledObject)
_, ok := unMarshalledObject["somefield2"]
```

[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/mmvdPnxmEJ)

Comment: The use of `map[string]interface{}`, though interesting, in this case is an overkill and overly complicate.

Comment: Agree with @pie-o-pah, this would hide type of somefield1 but it's very interesting to know it's working at all.

Answer (score 0):

If struct field is a pointer, JSON decoder will allocate new variable if the field is present or leave it nil if not. So I suggest to use pointers.

```
type Data struct {
    StrField *string
    IntField *int
}
...
if data.StrField != nil {
    handle(*data.StrField)
}
```

Comment: The value of the variable will be also nil if the value was "null" in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

By using `github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/struct` and jsonpb `github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb`, you can do like this:

```
func TestFunTest(t *testing.T) {
    p := &pb.KnownTypes{}
    e := UnmarshalString(`{"val":null}`, p)
    fmt.Println(e, p)
    p = &pb.KnownTypes{}
    e = UnmarshalString(`{"val":1}`, p)
    fmt.Println(e, p)
    p = &pb.KnownTypes{}
    e = UnmarshalString(`{"val":"string"}`, p)
    fmt.Println(e, p)
    p = &pb.KnownTypes{}
    e = UnmarshalString(`{}`, p)
    fmt.Println(e, p)
}
```

Output:

```
[ `go test -test.run="^TestFunTest$"` | done: 1.275431416s ]
    <nil> val:<null_value:NULL_VALUE > 
    <nil> val:<number_value:1 > 
    <nil> val:<string_value:"string" > 
    <nil> 
    PASS
```